# MFC Overlay Child Window Effect

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to know is there any solution discovered in MFC so far , which can give a child window following overlay effect:

[image]

Where "Before closing RegClean Pro " is a child window of the main window in background .
Is there any way to achieve such an effect in mfc?

Comment: Have you tried creating a dialog with a transparent background?

Comment: You think its a transparent dialog with image in between? Actually same effect is shown when the UAC pop message box is run.

Comment: Yes.  I think the child controls are centered in the dialog and the background is transparent.

Comment: But if I make child dialog transparent, the centre image will also get transparent , isn't it?

Comment: I don't think that's a problem if you control the rendering of the child controls.  You can control how the center image is rendered.